# Customizing Alfresco for Drag Down Option

Tags: open-source, alfresco

My requirement is to make a project with Alfresco who can manage document like WorkFlow,version history basically a document management System.
I have done research and development on it.Now in my Project the main requirement is that all the content in project should based on Drag and Drop Feature of adding Document to the content repository.

Is it possible with alfresco(all UI can be drag and Drop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible now...

New Alfresco 4.x support the Drag&Drop. You can drag and drop you document from your desktop to Alfresco Share client (web application - browser).

Check this out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7Yhwrcwk5k

By the way, seems that there is also an addon on named Alfresco Explorer drag and drops. I have no experience with that one.

Comment: Ok. Thats helps me..But you have told me "You can drag and drop you document from your desktop to Alfresco Share client (web application - browser)". I was asking UI(controls)like (ascx in asp.net) can be drag and drop or not?Do you have any idea regarding this.

Comment: I dont understand what asp has to do with Alfresco here?

Comment: Nothing i was just giving example.MY problem has been solved.Thankyou

Comment: I think you were asking about UI components drag and drop?
You cant build alfresco UI using drag and drop like for example Visual studio...

Comment: i have installed Altfesco community(alfresco-community-4.0.c-installer-win-x32).I did'nt get (Alfresco 4.x) from anywhere.Now the installed Alfresco community showing Evaluation Use Only.What does that mean?